# How to distribute $k$ distinct items into $r$ distinct groups with each groups receiving $a (=k-n)$ prizes at most?

Tags: combinatorics

> How to distribute $k$ distinct items into $p$ distinct groups with
>   each groups receiving $a (=k-n)$ prizes at most ?

This is my attempt to generalize the constraints of my [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79672/how-to-distribute-k-prizes-in-p-student-with-each-student-would-receive-k/79678#79678) and based on the discussion/comments in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79672/how-to-distribute-k-prizes-in-p-student-with-each-student-would-receive-k/79678#79678).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a list of $p$ sets of sets of size at most $a$.

The exponential generating function for sets of size at most $a$ is 
$$ 1+\frac{z}{1!}+\dots + \frac{z^a}{a!}$$

So, finally, you want to extract the coefficient of $\frac{z^k}{k!}$ from

$$ \left(1+\frac{z}{1!}+\dots+\frac{z^a}{a!}\right)^p.$$

Comment: Suppose that $p=k=3$ and $a=1$. Your formula yields $[z^3]\big((1+z)^3\big)=1$, but the correct answer is clearly $3!=6$, since the items are distinct.

Comment: Thanks, I am regarding exponential generating functions, and should have made that clear at the coefficient extraction stage.