# Books on shelves

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distribute $k$ distinct items into $r$ distinct groups with each groups receiving $a (=k-n)$ prizes at most?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79704/how-to-distribute-k-distinct-items-into-r-distinct-groups-with-each-groups-r)

How many ways you can use to put **N** books on **H** shelves, but the shelf's must contain not more than **X** books? I would like to solve it by [composition (number theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29)..but nothing.. Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: But all the books are the same!

Comment: Then please update the question accordingly as they are different problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_i$ be the number of books place on shelf $i$, $i=1,2,\dots,H$. Then you want the number of solutions of $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_H=N$$ with each $a_i$ an integer satisfying $0\le a_i\le X$. That question has come up multiple times on this site. Let's both try searching the site to see if we can find one of those previous appearances.