# Distributing $k$ distinct items among $r$ distinct groups without ordering

Tags: combinatorics

> Calculate the number of ways of distributing $k$ distinct items
>   among $r$ distinct groups such that each group receives at least
>   $a$ and at most $b$ items **and internal arrangement of items
>   within groups doesn't matter**.

For example suppose there are 2 groups and 3 items A, B, C. The distributions (AB, C) and (BA, C) must **not** be counted twice.

I've read a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79704/how-to-distribute-k-distinct-items-into-r-distinct-groups-with-each-groups-r). But the solution doesn't satisfy my second condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b,r$ be fixed.  For any $k$,  let $f(k)$ be the number of ways of arranging the $k$ distinct items into $r$ distinct groups with the specifications you give.  The exponential generating function for $f(k)$ is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k) \frac{x^k}{k!} = \left( \frac{x^a}{a!} + \frac{x^{a+1}}{(a+1)!} + \cdots + \frac{x^b}{b!} \right)^r
$$

So, for a fixed $k = k_0$, $f(k_0)$ is the coefficient of $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ in the power series above.  An explicit formula is
$$
f(k_0) = \frac{d^k}{dx^k} \left. \left[ \left( \frac{x^a}{a!} + \frac{x^{a+1}}{(a+1)!} + \cdots + \frac{x^b}{b!} \right)^r \right] \right|_{x = 0}
$$

I highly doubt there is any way to simplify this in general with so many parameters involved.  However, if you pose specific conditions on $a$ and $b$ you get some nicer results.  For example if $a = 0$ and $b = \infty$, then
the generating function becomes $(e^x)^r = e^{rx}$, so $f(k) = r^k$.
But you probably already knew that.

**Addendum:**

If we require that $|b - a| \le 1$, then either $b = a$ or $b = a+1$.

- If $b = a$, we want the coefficient of $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ in $\left(\frac{x^a}{a!}\right)^r$, which should be easy.
- If $b = a+1$, we want the coefficient of $\frac{x^k}{k!}$ in $\left(\frac{x^a}{a!} + \frac{x^{a+1}}{(a+1)!}\right)^r = \frac{x^{ar}}{(a!)^r} \left(1 + \frac{x}{a+1}\right)^r$.
  This ultimately evaluates to
  $$
  {r \choose k - ar} \cdot \frac { k! } { (a!)^r (a+1)^{k - ar} }
  $$

Comment: Thank you very much ... Let me see if I can work out from here :)

Comment: What if I impose one more condition?..... |b-a|<=1 .. Now the problem reduces to:- What is the coefficient of x^m in the expansion of (1 + a*x + b*x^2)^n Can you please help out?

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan I'll edit the answer.